# some kind of url dispatcher or proxy on tomcat

Tags: tomcat

Let imagine I have a host `myhost.com` with a Tomcat instance and some root webapplication running. If one goes to `myhost.com`, he can register there, and receives an url like `myhost.com/usr20`. Under this url, he can access his workspace and do his job. But this url `myhost.com/usr20` is still served by the same root application.

Any ideas how to do this on the fly, without creating symlinks or defining a new context and restarting Tomcat?

Comment: What is meant by _his workspace_ and _his job_? You mean the (registered) user can deploy his own JSPs (and other resources)?

Comment: no no. Just some job my webapp designed for. For example manage your photoalbums. You go to *myhost.com*, register there and receive your own url *myhost.com/usr20*. You can go there, login, manage your photoalbums, and send a link *myhost.com/usr20* to a friends to enjoy your photos.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is another webapp with a name conflicting with the user's URL (`usr20` in your example), you can do anything you want to. You need to have a central servlet, which will handle all the requests, and dispatch them to particular "subservlets", with the workspace name (e.g. `usr20`) as a parameter.

I'd strongly recommend you to get a look on some framework, like e.g. [Spring MVC](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/), which can handle this for you, and you can focus on your business logic, instead of reinventing the wheel and writing the central servlet and all the stuff.